# How are we going to use the "Europe" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the [europe](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag, which has been used on four questions as of this posting. Two talk about the European Union, one specifies no jurisdiction, and one takes place in Greece.

How are we going to use the [europe](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag?

The European Union is clearly not the same as individual countries in Europe. It acts on larger scales and has larger implications. I would think it warrants a second tag - [european-union](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union).

*However*, I'm also unsure if the [europe](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag would be helpful. Laws differ in countries across Europe. For example, Spain and Ukraine have different laws and governments. They just so happen to be on the same continent.

Comment: Before the jurisdiction thing runs completely out of control, it might be worth considering the use of a structured system of IDs for flagging jurisdictions. I maintain one at the [Legal Resource Registry](http://fbennett.github.io/legal-resource-registry/) that might be suitable (and it's the only thing of its kind that I know of). While it's easy to talk about committing other people's programming resources, a built-in lazy UI that preferences already-used jurisdiction tags, and allows posters to select fresh tags from the LRR set might fit the bill, so to speak.

Comment: @FrankBennett It might be worth a separate meta discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that it makes sense to have a [european-union](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/european-union) tag and that the [europe](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag is not useful in the vast majority of cases.

The only times I can see the [europe](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag being useful is to narrow a [legal-history](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-history) question to the region of Europe as compared to other similarly scoped regions or in cases where multiple separate countries within Europe are being asked about in the same question:

- How did the legal standing change for the death penalty in Europe between the years of 1455 and 1600?
- I bought a duck in Belgium, and brought it with my through France on my way to Spain. How many times should I have paid a duck tax? (with the need to also include the tags duck, travel, tax along with the three countries would exceed five tags).

Comment: I agree -- 'Europe' can mean lots of things, e.g. the 'Europe/European' means different things in ECHR, EU and EEA.